# Help! I cant figure out this setup for an indesign file

Tags: adobe-indesign, layout

I just need some extra guidance in my homework. So I need to set up a file in InDesign with a specific bleed, and I don't know what to do because InDesign won't let me set it past 6 in. Please help! These are the requirements:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your "trim size" (actual finish size) is 8 3/8" x 10 5/8"

the bleed wants to be 8 5/8" x 10 7/8"- this is 1/8" larger in each direction (1/4" total) than your "trim area"- set your bleed to 1/8" and you should be good.

It also looks like your margin wants to be 1/2" all the way around so that your "live area" is 1" smaller than your "trim area".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Trim Measurements** -- This is the *actual size* of the document. In InDesign, you use these measurements as your **base**. This is the **Document Size** in InDesign. This is the *final size* of the document delivered by the print provider.

**Bleed Measurements** --- Bleed measurements MINUS Trim measurements provides the **size of the bleed**. In this case `8-5/8 by 10-7/8 MINUS 8-3/8 by 10-5/8 = 2/8 by 2/8` Then you figure top and bottom, left and right - so DIVIDE this by 2. Leaving `2/8 ÷ 2 = 1/8` -- this is the size of your bleed - or 1/8" around all 4 sides, *outside* the trim measurements.

**Live Area Measurements** Sometimes referred to as **Safety Area** -- Trim measurements MINUS Live Area Measurements provides the size of the document **margins**. The space between the edge of the document to where any art or text should start. In this case `8-3/8 by 10-5/8 MINUS 7-3/8 by 9-5/8 = 1 by 1` Then you figure top and bottom, left and right - so DIVIDE this by 2. Leaving `1 ÷ 2 = 1/2` -- this is the size of your margin - So 1/2" all the way around all 4 sides of the document.

All this in an InDesign "New Document" window...
<sub>(You must convert fractions to decimals. If you don't know how to do that... 
 Merely divide the top number by the bottom number. For 5/8 you would use 5 ÷ 8 = .625.)</sub>

[image]

See [THIS ANSWER](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133340/confusion-about-how-bleed-works/133343#133343) for additional information.