# How to align and distribute a design evenly, with cut marks

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, template-design

New to illustrator here!

Im creating a simple instructions sheet for decal packaging. Im trying to get them to align properly with cut marks as they are being cut by hand. Whats the proper way to make a layout/template like this?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! Your crop marks seem to align so I don't understand what exactly the problem is. But it seems you don't have a margin so you will cut along the text. I would design a single label in a separate document, export a pdf with crop marks and place that in another document with the dimensions of the sheet. Keep the design and print sheet separate.

Comment: This: -- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/133343/3270 -- may help some. You want the artwork *within* the safety area and the cut marks should align with the trim edge.

Answer (score 1):

As the artwork exists, if one were to actually cut along your cut marks, you would essentially be also trimming off bits of the content, or trimming very, very close to the content....

[image]

You want to leave a bit of margin between the trim marks and the actual content....

[image]

This answer may help more: [Confusion about how bleed works](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/133340/confusion-about-how-bleed-works/133343#133343)

Content should be within the "safety" area. And cut marks should be aligned with the trim size.

[image]